# Incorrect syntax near 'Invest'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sqldataadapter

I am getting the following error when I run my code. Any help in identifying the cause will help.

```
Dim cmd_Email As New SqlCommand(
      "SELECT Main.P_Email FROM Invest INNER JOIN Main ON Invest.Ph_num = Main.Ph_num" & _
      "WHERE Invest.P_num =" & Ptcl & "UNION" & _
      "Select Main.P_Email FROM Invest INNER JOIN Main ON Invest.Ass1 = Main.Ph_num" & _
      "WHERE Invest.P_num =" & Ptcl & "UNION" & _
      "SELECT Main.P_Email FROM Invest INNER JOIN Main ON Invest.Ass2 = Main.Ph_num" & _
      "WHERE Invest.P_num = " & Ptcl, connection)
Dim read_Email As SqlDataReader = cmd_Email.ExecuteReader()
```

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.  Wouldn't your current sql read "WHERE Invest.P_num =111UNIONSELECT ..."

Comment: put that sql in a string variable and print it out so you can see it without all the concat operators, your errors will stand out to you much more clearly that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you T-SQL has a bad format, since there are no spaces between Ptcl variable and other instructions.

```
Dim cmd_Email As New SqlCommand(
  "SELECT Main.P_Email FROM Invest INNER JOIN Main ON Invest.Ph_num = Main.Ph_num " & _
  "WHERE Invest.P_num =" & Ptcl & " UNION " & _
  "Select Main.P_Email FROM Invest INNER JOIN Main ON Invest.Ass1 = Main.Ph_num " & _
  "WHERE Invest.P_num =" & Ptcl & " UNION " & _
  "SELECT Main.P_Email FROM Invest INNER JOIN Main ON Invest.Ass2 = Main.Ph_num " & _
  "WHERE Invest.P_num = " & Ptcl, connection)
```

The above query has been fixed regarding those spaces. But your best bet is to parametrize your query, to have a more readable structure, protect yourself from SQL injections, and have a more robust method to pass arguments to the query itself.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, This helped me a lot. I was also to able to parametrize the query.